# Deploy Production mode via SSH gets stuck at 'Static content deployment'

Tags: error, magento-2.0, deploy, deployment, ssh

So, I guess this is kinda vague and hard to explain, so I'll try to give some detail to help contextualise the problem.

I have a Magento 2.0.0 install, that I installed via cPanel's Installatron. When accessing the site via SSH using Terminal, I am able to set the mode to 'developer' using `deploy:mode:set developer`, but when attempting to use `deploy:mode:set production`, Terminal will display `Enabled maintenance mode`, followed by `Static content deployment start`, and then thats it, nothing else happens. Terminal just sits there doing nothing until I `ctrl+c` to stop it doing nothing.

I've attempted this a couple times, and waited an hour or longer sometimes for something to happen, and still nothing. Has anyone experienced something like this before? Any light anyone could shed on this topic would be amazingly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Wait at least for 10 to 15 minutes. Deploying static content can take time and in this command the progress of the deploy is Not rendered before its finished

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not detailed much about problem!, 
Can you please try to run below command ?:

```
Temporarily workaround: php magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
```